# How can I access Native api in NativeScript when I use Typescript

Tags: nativescript

When I create two new apps with tns, one is the regular js version and one is with typescript. I get a strange error in the typescript version when I try to access a native library.

When I create a loaded function with a console.log(pow(x,y)), it works fine with the js version but the typescript version crashes with this error.

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'pow'.
```

Why?

TS:

```
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { HelloWorldModel } from "./main-view-model";

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();
}

export function loaded() {
    console.log('Hello World')
    console.log('pow(2.5, 3) = ', pow(2.5, 3));
}
```

JS:

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();
}

function loaded() {
    console.log('hello world')
    console.log('pow(2.5, 3) = ', pow(2.5, 3));
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
exports.loaded = loaded;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

TypeScript is strongly typed language and needs an explicit type definition for each variable (e.g. like ***pow***). Instead of casting to `any`, you could provide definition files pre-generated by NativeScript that will give you typing and IntelliSense for the native Android and iOS APIs.

The latest release of NativeScript by default is creating the app without the platform declaration files (**android17.d.ts** for Android and **ios.d.ts** for iOS) and without those files, your TypeScript simply does not know about the native APIs references.
The reason not to include the definition files - those are enormously big and are needed only when the developers are going to use TypeScript (or Angular) + access to native APIs.

**The solution:**

1.) Install the definition files as a developer dependency

```
npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev
```

This will install your platform declaraion files in *node_modules/tns-platform-declarations*

2.) Create **references.d.ts** in your main app directory and **add** the following

```
// SEE the updated paths below
```

Now you are good to go!

**UPDATE (as of October 2017 - with installing tns-core-modules 3.x.x (or above) and tns-platform-declarations 3.x.x (or above)):**
The npm plugin now has a different structure so these are the proper paths (create `references.d.ts` file in the root directory and place the one below)

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android/android.d.ts" />
```

**Important**: Your **tsconfig.json** should look like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds logical - i'm new to typescript and NativeScript. Thank you very much!!

Comment: for ios the path is  in a sub-folder called `ios`. ```/// <reference path="../node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/tns-core-modules/ios/ios.d.ts" />```

Comment: Thanks @Rjk. But now I get "The reference includes files outside the project". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Although this answer works for me, if I'm careful to grab the the latest pre-release components.  I still get syntax errors https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2970

Comment: @NickIliev This fixed my Intellisense.  Unfortunately, after installing `tns-core-modules@next` and `tns-platform-declarations@next` and modifying the files you indicate above, my TypeScript files are not compiled by `tns`.

Comment: @NickIliev As +vossad01 stated this is caused by the app.ts file where you import * app as app from 'application'; ERR [ts] Cannot find module 'application'.

Comment: Hey @BaconJuice, and vossad01  remove the include section from your tsconfig.json (as updated) and something important in order for your tsc to work in VSCode - remove any predefined settings in .vscode/settings.json as they are casuing for the installed typescript in the node_modules to fail

Comment: shouldn't this just be `npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev` as this is only needed at development time and not at run time?

Comment: @gabelkonus absolutely! Corrected the snippet right away

Comment: Is `ios-runtime` and `android-runtime` also needed?