# How to change TimePicker in NativeScript to show the time in 24-hour format?

Tags: time, typescript, native, timepicker, nativescript

In NativeScript, there is the TimePicker, which one shows a time, but in 12-hour format. I have a problem, because in my database all of my times are saved in string (in format "23:59").

I canot set hour, e.g. 14.

I have an idea, to convert string with `split(':')` and changing period AM to PM, but i cannot see any usefull method to do that. Please, help.

Comment: I think the timepicker even doesn't return AM or PM when you use the hour property

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native APIs to set the 24-hour format.
TimePicker in NativeScript is using **UIDatePicker** in iOS
and **android.widget.TimePicker** in Android

page.js

```
   "use strict";
    var application = require("application");
    function onLoaded(args) {
        var page = args.object;
        var tPicker = page.getViewById("tPicker");
        if (application.android) {
            tPicker.android.setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
            tPicker.hour = 23;
            tPicker.minute = 59;
        }
        else if (application.ios) {
            // a bit hacky solution
            // important set the country not the language for locale
            var local = NSLocale.alloc().initWithLocaleIdentifier("NL");
            tPicker.ios.locale = local;
            tPicker.hour = 23;
            tPicker.minute = 59;
        }
    }
    exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```

page.xml

```
<TimePicker id="tPicker"></TimePicker>
```

Comment: I rewrite this to TypeScript and unfortunetly the problem still exist. "cannnot read property android of undefined", but thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get your time pickeer by id.. the id should be present in your xml file. The code sample I have posted is tested and works on both platforms. Also notice that I am giving an example that happens in onLoaded event .. <Page loaded="onLoaded">

Comment: When developing NativeScript with TS you will also need the reference to the decaration files for accessing the native APIs .. take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523071/how-can-i-access-native-api-in-nativescript-when-i-use-typescript/37524018#37524018