# Unable to access NSLocale on TimePicker

Tags: angular, nativescript

Im trying to set a Nativescript TimePicker to 24h format and found some solutions for this on other threads, like this one [How to change TimePicker in NativeScript to show the time in 24-hour format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827752/how-to-change-timepicker-in-nativescript-to-show-the-time-in-24-hour-format/38828270#38828270) . The only problem is that 'NSLocale' and 'java' aren't recognized and thus cause my app to crash. How do I import these properties?

My code is as follows:

```
onLoaded(args) {
        const timePicker: TimePicker = args.object;
        timePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
        if (isAndroid) {
            timePicker.android.setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
            timePicker.hour = 23;
            timePicker.minute = 59;
        } else if (isIOS) {
            // a bit hacky solution
            // important set the country not the language for locale
            const local = NSLocale.alloc().initWithLocaleIdentifier("NL");
            timePicker.ios.locale = local;
            timePicker.hour = 23;
            timePicker.minute = 59;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about typescript errors? If then just configure [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) plugin Or simply do `declare var java, NSLocale;` at top of your file.