# How to give Nativescript timepicker 24-hour format instead of 12-hour?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nativescript, timepicker

I use `<TimePicker class="activity-picker" />` to add a time picker to my android application. But the time picker shows the time in a 12-hour format instead of 24-hours. I want to be able to pick the time in a 24-hour format.

I already tried to use `<TimePicker class="activity-picker" :hourFormat="24" />` but the format does not change.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38827752/6355004