# How to access android's R object in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to access android's `R` object in NativeScript with Angular but I haven't had any success. The instructions [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript) say to do it like this:

```
android.R.color.holo_purple
```

But when I try to import the `android` variable from the `application` module or the `tns-core-modules/platform` module I get an error that the `R` property on the `android` object is undefined. How do I get access to `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to import `android` variable from `application` module. it is automatically available by default at runtime. to remove compile time error `property doesn't exists` just declare the variable named `android` to `any`.

for example.

```
declare var android:any;
export class AppComponent{
  let holoPurple=android.R.color.holo_purple;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't get existing answers to work in latest nativescript / angular. I resolved it with the following:

Created a file App_Resources/Android/values/keys.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="key_name">xxxxxx</string>
</resources>
```

Import these

```
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';
import * as utils from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils';
```

then to grab the string

```
const context = app.android.context;
const res = context.getResources().getString(utils.ad.resources.getStringId('key_name'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to use following 
`import * as application from "@nativescript/core/application";
import * as utils from "@nativescript/core/utils";`

Answer (score 0):

The `android` here is the main namespace for the Android SDK and not the `android` property from the `application` module.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524018/4936697) for instruction on how to access the native SDK via TypeScript or use the instruction from [the related documentation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript#intellisense-and-access-to-native-apis-via-typescript)

Comment: I did this but am still not able to access `android.R`. I am able to use the it when creating a new object like this `let myObj = new android.native.sdk.class.Example`. That works just fine. But if I try to use `android.R.color.Red` without the `new` keyword by passing it to a function or setting it to a property it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this comment on how to access a resource file via the `application` module https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/260#issuecomment-169361745