# Having issue while accessing Android packages in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

As the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages#access-android-packages) suggests:

> The Android packages are available in the JavaScript/TypeScript global context and are the entry point for accessing Android APIs. Think of them as of TypeScript/C# namespaces, or the way to access sets of classes. For example, the `android.view` package grants access to classes like `android.view.View` - the base of all view elements in Android.

But when I try to access any package it gives me following error:
[image]

**`Error: Cannot find name 'android'`**

I don't know what is wrong here maybe the documentation is outdated or I am missing something. If you know that please let me know please let me know I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with TypeScript (and even with plain JavaScript if you want intelliSense for the native APIs) you need to have explicit declarations (usually coming from typings files with *.d.ts extension). From the same documentation article, you have referred

> Note: To have access and Intellisense for the native APIs with
>   NativeScript + TypeScript or NativeScript + Angular projects, you have
>   to add a dev dependency to `tns-platform-declarations`. More details
>   about accessing native APIs with TypeScript can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript#intellisense-and-access-to-the-native-apis-via-typescript).

Detailed instructions for how to use `tns-platform-declarations` can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523071/how-can-i-access-native-api-in-nativescript-when-i-use-typescript/37524018#37524018) or [in the plugin's instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations)

Comment: By root directory it meant Project directory or 'app' folder inside it for creating that file?

Comment: root directory = The Project main directory

Comment: Thank you much for the help, it worked. God bless you.