# NativeScript Google API

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript

I can't seem to determine what to use for the Task generic described in the Google API documentation. Could anyone assist me? Here is the guide I was following and I was converting it to NativeScript Angular:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I just had to import the follow:

```
import Task = com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
```

Comment: For NativeScript you can enable the TypeScript declarations files with `tns-platform-declarations` - this will provide you with IntelliSense for the converted APIs and also eliminate the need to explicitly cast to `any` for the Android namespaces. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524018/4936697