# How to use native Android class in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript with Angular. I want to use ActivityManager class in my app.

My question is how to import the ActivityManager class in my typescript file

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access Native api in NativeScript when I use Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523071/how-can-i-access-native-api-in-nativescript-when-i-use-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please give snippet for how to use ActivityManager class.